# Postgresql 9.4 query gets progressively slower when joining TSTZRANGE with &&

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-performance

I am running a query that gets progressively slower as records are added. **Records are added continuously via an automated process (bash calling psql).** I would like to correct this bottle neck; however, I don't know what my best option is.

This is the output from pgBadger:
[image: Chart of queries executed per hour]

```
Hour    Count   Duration    Avg duration
00      9,990   10m3s       60ms     <---ignore this hour
02      1       60ms        60ms     <---ignore this hour
03      4,638   1m54s       24ms     <---queries begin with table empty
04      30,991  55m49s      108ms    <---first full hour of queries running
05      13,497  58m3s       258ms
06      9,904   58m32s      354ms
07      10,542  58m25s      332ms
08      8,599   58m42s      409ms
09      7,360   58m52s      479ms
10      6,661   58m57s      531ms
11      6,133   59m2s       577ms
12      5,601   59m6s       633ms
13      5,327   59m9s       666ms
14      4,964   59m12s      715ms
15      4,759   59m14s      746ms
16      4,531   59m17s      785ms
17      4,330   59m18s      821ms
18      939     13m16s      848ms
```

The table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Parent" (
    "ParentID" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Details1" VARCHAR
);
```

Table `"Parent"` has a one to many relationship with table `"Foo"`:

```
CREATE TABLE "Foo" (
    "FooID" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "ParentID" int4 NOT NULL REFERENCES "Parent" ("ParentID"),
    "Details1" VARCHAR
);
```

Table `"Foo"` has a one to many relationship with table `"Bar"`:

```
CREATE TABLE "Bar" (
    "FooID" int8 NOT NULL REFERENCES "Foo" ("FooID"),
    "Timerange" tstzrange NOT NULL,
    "Detail1" VARCHAR,
    "Detail2" VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT "Bar_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("FooID", "Timerange")
);
CREATE INDEX  "Bar_FooID_Timerange_idx" ON "Bar" USING gist("FooID", "Timerange");
```

**Additionally, table `"Bar"` may not contain overlapping `"Timespan"` values for the same `"FooID"` or `"ParentID"`.** I have created a trigger that fires after any `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` that prevents overlapping ranges.

The **trigger** includes **a section** that look **similar** to this:

```
WITH
    "cte" AS (
        SELECT
            "Foo"."FooID",
            "Foo"."ParentID",
            "Foo"."Details1",
            "Bar"."Timespan"
        FROM
            "Foo"
            JOIN "Bar" ON "Foo"."FooID" = "Bar"."FooID"
        WHERE
            "Foo"."FooID" = 1234
    )
SELECT
    "Foo"."FooID",
    "Foo"."ParentID",
    "Foo"."Details1",
    "Bar"."Timespan"
FROM
    "cte"
    JOIN "Foo" ON 
        "cte"."ParentID" = "Foo"."ParentID"
        AND "cte"."FooID" <> "Foo"."FooID"
    JOIN "Bar" ON
        "Foo"."FooID" = "Bar"."FooID"
        AND "cte"."Timespan" && "Bar"."Timespan";
```

The results from `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=7258.08..15540.26 rows=1 width=130) (actual time=8.052..147.792 rows=1 loops=1)
  Join Filter: ((cte."FooID" <> "Foo"."FooID") AND (cte."ParentID" = "Foo"."ParentID"))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 76
  CTE cte
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.68..7257.25 rows=1000 width=160) (actual time=1.727..1.735 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Function Scan on "fn_Bar"  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=104) (actual time=1.699..1.701 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Index Scan using "Foo_pkey" on "Foo" "Foo_1"  (cost=0.42..7.24 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.023..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ("FooID" = "fn_Bar"."FooID")
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..8256.00 rows=50 width=86) (actual time=1.828..147.188 rows=77 loops=1)
        ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=108) (actual time=1.730..1.740 rows=1 loops=1)
   **** ->  Index Scan using "Bar_FooID_Timerange_idx" on "Bar"  (cost=0.41..8.23 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.093..145.314 rows=77 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((cte."Timespan" && "Timespan"))
  ->  Index Scan using "Foo_pkey" on "Foo"  (cost=0.42..0.53 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=77)
        Index Cond: ("FooID" = "Bar"."FooID")
Planning time: 1.490 ms
Execution time: 147.869 ms
```

(**** emphasis mine)

This seems to show that 99% of the work being done is in the `JOIN` from `"cte"` to `"Bar"` (via `"Foo"`) ... but it is already using the appropriate index... it's still just too slow.

So I ran:

```
SELECT 
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('"Bar"')) AS "Table",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('"Bar_FooID_Timerange_idx"')) AS "Index";
```

Results:

```
    Table    |    Index
-------------|-------------
 283 MB      | 90 MB
```

Does an index of this size (relative to the table) offer much in terms of read performance? I was considering a sudo-partition where the index is replaced with several partial indexes... maybe the partials would have less to maintain (and read) and performance would improve. I have never seen this done, just an idea. If this is an option, I can't think of any good way to limit the segments given this would be on a `TSTZRANGE` value.

I also think adding the `"ParentID"` to `"Bar"` would speed things up, but I don't want to denormalize.

What other choices do I have?

---

## Impact of changes recommended by Erwin Brandstetter

[image: Chart of queries executed per hour]

At the peak performance (hour 18:00), the process was adding **14.5 records per second consistently**... up from 1.15 records per second.

**This was the result of:**

1. Adding `"ParentID"` to table `"Bar"`
2. Adding a foreign key constraint to `"Foo" ("ParentID", "FooID")`
3. Adding `EXCLUDE USING gist ("ParentID" WITH =, "Timerange" WITH &&) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` *(btree_gist module already installed)*

Comment: Is there  particular reason for using a CTE? In PostgreSQL the CTE is an optimiser fence that prevents some optimisations. I would try it without.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - The CTE is required later in the query, only the pertinent portion is represented per `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`; however, to your point, the results are the same... the bottle neck is in the JOIN from CTE (or the rewritten subquery) to table `"Bar"` via `"Foo"`.

Comment: With all these fake table and index names, it's pretty difficult to follow what's going on in that explain plan.

Comment: `"ParentID" int4 NOT NULL REFERENCES "Parents" ("ParentID"),` a supporting index for parent_id is indicated here: `create index on "Foo" ("parentID");`

Comment: @DavidAldridge - sorry about the cryptic code - EXPLAIN ANALYSE has been updated.

Comment: First step to test the CTE-hypothesis: replace the CTE by a (temporal) view. The syntax is almost the same. BTW: do you have autovacuum disabled? Do you have many stale sessions ("idle in transaction") ? How many active concurrent sessions are there during the day?

Comment: @wildplasser - The DDL for `"Foo"` shows `CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY` ... I was under the impression that postgres automaticly puts an index on foregin keys... no?

Comment: No. Only the "target" for the FK needs to have at least a UNIQUE constraint. [but you still need to get rid of the cte, IMHO]

Comment: @wildplasser - autovacuum is on and sessions are minimal as I am the only one using this server (the client application does open several sessions for different reasons, but I am the only active user). As for the CTE, I rewrote the query without the CTE and the bottleneck is still the same... 99% of the query time is spent joining to `"Bar"` with the index scan on `"Bar_FooID_Timerange_idx"`.

Comment: The increasing execution times during the day suggest the presence of another process inserting or updating the data.

Comment: @wildplasser - you're correct, I failed to mention the automated process that is continuously adding records to this table. The query in question is part of the trigger that fires when a record is modified... this bottleneck ends up slowing down my write performance because it is called in the trigger.

Comment: Please clarify `not contain overlapping "Timespan" values for the same "FooID" or "ParentID"`. This boils down to: `not contain overlapping "Timespan" values for the same "ParentID"`, correct?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - thats correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)

> Additionally, table `"Bar"` may not contain overlapping `"Timespan"`
> values for the same `"FooID"` or `"ParentID"`. I have created a trigger
> that fires after any `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` that prevents
> overlapping ranges.

I suggest you use an exclusion constraint instead, which is much simpler, safer and faster:

You need to install the additional module [**`btree_gist`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) first. See instructions and explanation in this related answer:

- [Store the day of the week and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895140/store-the-day-of-the-week-and-time/19897592#19897592)

And you need to include `"ParentID"` in the table `"Bar"` redundantly, which will be a small price to pay. Table definitions could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Foo" (
   "FooID"    serial PRIMARY KEY
   "ParentID" int4 NOT NULL REFERENCES "Parent"
   "Details1" varchar
   CONSTRAINT foo_parent_foo_uni UNIQUE ("ParentID", "FooID")  -- required for FK
);

CREATE TABLE "Bar" (
   "ParentID"  int4 NOT NULL,
   "FooID"     int4 NOT NULL REFERENCES "Foo" ("FooID"),
   "Timerange" tstzrange NOT NULL,
   "Detail1"   varchar,
   "Detail2"   varchar,
   CONSTRAINT "Bar_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("FooID", "Timerange"),
   CONSTRAINT bar_foo_fk
      FOREIGN KEY ("ParentID", "FooID") REFERENCES "Foo" ("ParentID", "FooID"),
   CONSTRAINT bar_parent_timerange_excl
      EXCLUDE USING gist ("ParentID" WITH =, "Timerange" WITH &&)
);
```

I also changed the data type for  `"Bar"."FooID"` from <strike>`int8`</strike> to `int4`. It references `"Foo"."FooID"`, which is a `serial`, i.e. `int4`. Use the matching type **`int4`** (or just `integer`) for several reasons, one of them being performance.

You don't need a trigger any more (at least not for this task), and you don't create the index <strike>`"Bar_FooID_Timerange_idx"`</strike> any more, since it's created implicitly by the exclusion constraint.

A btree index on `("ParentID", "FooID")` will most probably be useful, though:

```
CREATE INDEX bar_parentid_fooid_idx ON "Bar" ("ParentID", "FooID");
```

Related:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

I chose `UNIQUE ("ParentID", "FooID")` and not the other way round for a reason, since there is another index with leading `"FooID"` in either table:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Aside: [I never use double-quoted CaMeL-case identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860) in Postgres. Only doing that here to comply with your layout.

#### Avoid redundant column

If you cannot or will not include `"Bar"."ParentID"` redundantly, there is another *rogue* way - on the condition that `"Foo"."ParentID"` is **never updated**. Make sure of that, with a trigger for instance.

You can fake an `IMMUTABLE` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_parent_of_foo(int)
  RETURNS int AS
'SELECT "ParentID" FROM public."Foo" WHERE "FooID" = $1'
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

I schema-qualified the table name to make sure, assuming `public`. Adapt to your schema.

More:

- [CONSTRAINT to check values from a remotely related table (via join etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107034/constraint-to-check-values-from-a-remotely-related-table-via-join-etc/27107470#27107470)
- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

Then use it in the exclusion constraint:

```
   CONSTRAINT bar_parent_timerange_excl
      EXCLUDE USING gist (f_parent_of_foo("FooID") WITH =, "Timerange" WITH &&)
```

While saving one redundant `int4` column, the constraint will be more expensive to verify and the whole solution depends on more preconditions.

#### Handle conflicts

You could wrap `INSERT` and `UPDATE` into a plpgsql function and trap possible exceptions from the exclusion constraint (`23P01     exclusion_violation`) to handle it some way.

```
INSERT ...

EXCEPTION
    WHEN exclusion_violation
    THEN  -- handle conflict
```

Complete code example:

- [Handling EXCEPTION and return result from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985757/handling-exception-and-return-result-from-function/16985848#16985848)

#### Handle conflict in Postgres 9.5

In Postgres **9.5** you can handle `INSERT` directly with the new "UPSERT" implementation. [The documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> The optional `ON CONFLICT` clause specifies an alternative action to
> raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error.
> For each individual row proposed for insertion, either the insertion
> proceeds, or, if an **arbiter** constraint or index specified by
> `conflict_target` is violated, the alternative `conflict_action` is
> taken. `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` simply avoids inserting a row as its
> alternative action. `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` updates the existing row
> that conflicts with the row proposed for insertion as its alternative action.

However:

> Note that exclusion constraints are not supported with `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.

But you can still use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, thus avoiding possible `exclusion_violation` exceptions. Just check whether any rows were actually updated, which is cheaper:

```
INSERT ... 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT bar_parent_timerange_excl DO NOTHING;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   -- handle conflict
END IF;
```

This example restricts the check to the given exclusion constraint. (I named the constraint explicitly for this purpose in the table definition above.) Other possible exceptions are not caught.

Comment: _+1 for the compound foreign key (I never thought of that in this context)._ The `EXCLUDE` is desirable, but I previously (prematurely) ruled it out. In my original question, **the trigger that fires does not simply check for a conflict... it uses the conflicting record (and business rules) to calculate a fix for the conflict** (essentially an `UPDATE` to the offending record). When using an `EXCLUDE` constraint, is it possible to return the offending record when a conflict is found? ...maybe using pl/pgsql with `EXCEPTION WHEN...`

Comment: @losthorse: Consider the alternatives I added above.

Comment: I added the impact of your recommendations to the end of my question.