# INSERT or UPDATE based on changing timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, exclusion-constraint

I have a table where I record events. These events will come into the system once a minute, per user - on the order of 10's of thousands a minute. But I don't need to save *all* of them.
If an event comes in within 90 seconds of the previous event, I want to update the previous row. If it's been more than 90 seconds, I want to insert a new row.

Example table:

```sql
create table events (
  id serial,
  user_id int references users(id) not null,
  created_at timestamp not null default now(),
  updated_at timestamp not null default now(),
  ...some other event columns here...
);

create index idx_events_user_id_updated_at on events (user_id, updated_at desc);
```

And the pseudocode would be something like:

1. Fetch last event for user
2. If `updated_at` is within the last 90 seconds:

   1. Update row, including `updated_at` with `now()`
3. Otherwise:

   1. Insert new row

Is there a way to do this with a single Postgres statement?

I'm aware of `on conflict`, but I don't think it'll work for this use-case. The `(user_id, updated_at)` pair *could* be defined as a unique constraint, which could be used to trigger an `on conflict`, but the timestamps are arbitrary. These events come in "every minute", but not *exactly* on a minute (or even *exactly* a minute apart, due to network latency, server latency, etc etc, hence using 90 seconds to give a 30 second buffer). Truncating the timestamps to the minute would reduce the feature's usefulness, so I'd hate to do that just to handle upserts more cleanly.

Comment: When you say "update row", that means you want to keep only the `created_at` and otherwise use all new values?

Comment: Yes, that's correct... `created_at`, `user_id`, and `id` - the other fields will update to the newest values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this with a single Postgres statement?

Can be done with an UPSERT command. You need an [`EXCLUSION` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) on the timestamp range. For the leading integer column `user_id`, the additional module [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) must be installed. See:

- [How to ensure entries with non-overlapping time ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716095/how-to-ensure-entries-with-non-overlapping-time-ranges/61779939#61779939)

```sql
ALTER TABLE events
  ADD CONSTRAINT user_90sec
  EXCLUDE USING gist (user_id WITH =, tsrange(updated_at, updated_at + interval '90 sec') WITH &&);
```

Notably, the same doesn't work for `timestamptz` because `timestamptz + interval` is only `STABLE`, while `timestamp + interval` is `IMMUTABLE` as required for the implied GiST index (or any index for that matter).

Query:

```sql
WITH input_rows(user_id, data) AS (
   VALUES
      (1, 'foo_new')  -- your input here
    , (2, 'bar_new')
    , (3, 'baz_new')
    -- more?
   )
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO events (user_id, data) 
   SELECT user_id, data FROM input_rows
   ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT user_90sec DO NOTHING
   RETURNING user_id
   )
UPDATE events e
SET    updated_at = LOCALTIMESTAMP
     , data = i.data
FROM   input_rows i
LEFT   JOIN ins USING (user_id)
WHERE  ins.user_id IS NULL
AND    e.user_id = i.user_id
AND    e.updated_at > LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '90 sec';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/seczOkK8)

This assumes at most **one** row per `user_id` in the input.

And no concurrent, competing writes. Else, there may be race conditions due to the tiny, but unavoidable time gap between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. (`ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` is not allowed based on an exclusion constraint.)

Also, no ambiguous data types in the input, or you must add an explicit cast. See:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)
- [Postgresql 9.4 query gets progressively slower when joining TSTZRANGE with &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987739/postgresql-9-4-query-gets-progressively-slower-when-joining-tstzrange-with/33990737#33990737)

Depending on details of your case, there may well be faster solutions. Like, just write all incoming rows (with a substantially faster `COPY` command), and later consolidate in bulk operations.

While sticking with this solution, it may be faster to add a generated column for the `tsrange` and base the exclusion constraint (and its implied GiST index) on that. Bloats the table row a bit, though. See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-generated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this feature existed! Thanks for the detailed write up!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to create a stored procedure with an upsert block, i.e.:

```
UPDATE ...
IF NOT FOUND THEN 
  INSERT ...
END IF
```

Start by assuming that the record exists and do an `UPDATE`. Include a `WHERE` clause that checks if the record was updated less than 90 seconds ago.

If nothing was updated it means that either there was no previous record or the previous record was updated more than 90 seconds ago - either way you need to do an `INSERT`

From the clients perspective there will only be a single call (execute the procedure) and most of the time there will only be a single `UPDATE` on the server, however the second `INSERT` will be needed sometimes.

Comment: `if not found` - I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the suggestion! Fairly straightforward solution to the problem =)