# Error when creating a gin index with table of millions of documents

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, plpgsql

I have a table with millions of text documents in a Postgres 14.7 DB. When I try to generate a GIN index I get this error:

```sql
create index idx__txt_document__doc_text__gin on txt_document using gin(to_tsvector('simple', doc_text));
```

```
ERROR:  string is too long for tsvector (4040510 bytes, max 1048575 bytes)
Time: 6221.251 ms (00:06.221)
```

Is there a way to find out the offending text id?

I get the same error when I create a temp table that contains the text id and the length of document's tsvector.

```sql
create temp table tmp_foo as
select id, length(to_tsvector('simple', doc_text))
from txt_document;
```

```
ERROR:  string is too long for tsvector (4040510 bytes, max 1048575 bytes)
CONTEXT:  parallel worker
Time: 1912.090 ms (00:01.912)
```

Any idea how to get the text that creates the error?

I found the largest document which is about 7MB but creating the tsvector works just fine.

```sql
select length(to_tsvector('simple', doc_text)) from txt_document where id = ID_LARGEST_TEXT;
```

Comment: can you suply some data with your table?

Comment: It is plain text generated from HTML files. Does that answer your question?

Comment: no, to reproduce the problem it needs a [mre], so some rows are needed, as the pr4oblem is the text in the table

Comment: That is what I'm asking. ;-) Is there a way to find the text that is throwing the error? For instance, I have randomly selected 100,000 documents and I was able to generate the index.

Comment: how about not use ts_vector when searching for length, but only text

Comment: Not sure what you mean. "Searching for length" of what?

Comment: i mean length('simple', doc_text)  to chekc for vaalues that have more than 1,800.000 bytes

Comment: I don't think there is a very a good of doing that.  I think you would need to do something like a binary search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through your table, catch the exception, and `RAISE` a notice (or whatever):

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT id, doc_text FROM tbl
   LOOP
      PERFORM to_tsvector('simple', r.doc_text);
   END LOOP;
   
   -- Force error for debugging:
   -- PERFORM to_tsvector('simple', string_agg('longwordnr' || g, ' ')) FROM generate_series (1, 100000) g;  
EXCEPTION
   WHEN program_limit_exceeded THEN
-- WHEN SQLSTATE '54000' THEN  -- the same with error code
      RAISE NOTICE 'Row with this "id" exceeds ts_vector length: %', r.id;
END
$do$
```

Using a [`DO` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) to execute a PL/pgSQL code block quickly.-

I got the error code from provoking the same error. Postgres error messages by default add this line:

```
...
SQL state: 54000
```

Your client seems to suppress it, or you did not include it in the question.
About [Postgres error codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).

About the `EXCEPTION` clause:

- [Handling EXCEPTION and return result from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985757/handling-exception-and-return-result-from-function/16985848#16985848)
- [Perform action before exception call in Postgres trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650458/perform-action-before-exception-call-in-postgres-trigger-function/25653276#25653276)

Note that duplicative lexemes in input strings are stored "compressed" in a `tsvector`. Hence, the longest string does not necessarily produce the longest `tsvector`. Consider this demo:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GbUYAiVJ)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit annoying, but you could create a wrapper function which catches the error and converts it to NULL (or some other sentinel value):

```
create or replace function jjj_to(text) returns tsvector language plpgsql as $$
  begin 
    return to_tsvector('simple',$1); 
  exception when others then 
    return null; 
  end $$;
```

Then:

```
select id from txt_document where jjj_to(doc_text) is null;
```